# Making Tuiles in a frying pan?

Tags: cookies

My parents' oven is having issues (the bottom element has stopped working.)  One idea I had to keep cooking was to make Tuiles on the stove top.  It seems to me like it might work.

I'm assuming that I'll have to either cover the pan or flip the cooking tuile.

I can't find any recipes for a stove top variation.  Anyone have any experience or advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it’s very well doable on a stove-top. You can use a non-stick pan and it would work great.

My experience with pans is, due to surface curvature, it’s better to use a small pan and fry your tuile spread all over the pan.